# Jquery , flip rotate image

Tags: jquery, image, rotation, flip

I'm looking for a way to rotate and flip image at the same time .i used this : 
 to flip:

```
$('.images').css({
'-webkit-transform' : 'scaleX(-1)',
'-o-transform' : 'scaleX(-1)',
'-webkit-transform' : 'scaleX(-1)',
'transform' : 'scaleX(-1)',
'filter':'FlipH'});
```

to rotate :

```
$('.images').css({
'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+-ui.value+'deg)',
'-o-transform' : 'rotate('+-ui.value+'deg)',
'-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+-ui.value+'deg)',
'-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+-ui.value+'deg)',                           
'transform' :'rotate('+-ui.value+'deg)'      

             });
```

I want to keep image flipping while rotate , can someone Help , thank you all.

Comment: Please be more precise and void just to copy/paste code. thanks

Comment: The two codes above work fine . the first one to flip image , the second to rotate image . what i want is : when image is flipped ; i want to rotate it and keeping it flipped . with a slider . and "ui.value" is a slider variable that change from 0 to 360 Degree . Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Just combine them

```
$('.images').css({
        '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+-ui.value +'deg)' + 'scaleX(-1)',
        '-o-transform' : 'rotate('+-ui.value +'deg)' + 'scaleX(-1)',
        '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+-ui.value +'deg)' + 'scaleX(-1)',
        '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+-ui.value +'deg)' + 'scaleX(-1)',                           
        'transform' :'rotate('+-ui.value +'deg)' + 'scaleX(-1)'     
});
```

Comment: I used only  

    $('.images').css({

    'transform' :'rotate('+-ui.value +'deg) scaleX(-1)'     
                                                                      });                                                                  and it wroks fine